# NativeScript ListView Item Template

Tags: android, css, listview, nativescript

I want to create a list view NativeScript with custom item view. I'm using GridLayout to do that.
The problem is: **There is large space between rows item.**

These are what I've done:

XML:

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
<ActionBar title="Welcome">
    <android>
        <NavigationButton android.systemIcon="ic_menu_emoticons" icon="res://icon" tap="showSlideout"/>
    </android>
</ActionBar>
<ListView items="{{ items }}">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto,*" class="threads-list-wrapper" height="100">
            <Image row="0" col="0" src="{{ photo }}"></Image>
            <StackLayout row="0" col="1" class="" orientation="vertical">
                <Label class="h1" text="{{title}}"></Label>
                <Label text="{{ body }}"></Label>
                <Label text="{{ date }}"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

CSS

```
.threads-list-wrapper {
padding: 15;
}

.threads-list-wrapper > Image {
height: 64;
width: 64;
margin-right: 15;
}
```

CODE:

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var model = new observableModule.Observable();

exports.loaded = function (args) {
    var items = [
        {
            photo: 'res://icon',
            title: 'Ardiansyah Putra',
            body: 'Ini adalah pesan yang saya kirimkan kepada anda, mohon cepat dibalas ya',
            date: 'Just Now'
        },
        {
            photo: 'res://icon',
            title: 'Bagus Putra',
            body: 'Ini adalah pesan yang saya kirimkan kepada anda, mohon cepat dibalas ya',
            date: '12 Jan'
        }
    ];
    var page = args.object;
    model.set("items", items);
    page.bindingContext = model;
};
```

RESULT:
[image]

Comment: The GridLayout innside your template uses row="auto" and height="100". Try removing height

Comment: @Manijak it seems no effect bro

Comment: as well to remove height check your CSS class "threads-list-wrapper" and make sure it is not setting height. Also try to set  rows="*"

Comment: @NickIliev: Unfortunately it's not working, I have no idea why if I remove the Image tag everything goes well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is causing the white space in your case , but here is a snippet where after stripping all the CSS there are no extra white spaces generated in the list-view template.

```
<GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *">
    <Image col="0" src="res://icon" stretch="none" />
    <StackLayout col="1" >
        <Label class="h1" text="{{title}}"></Label>
        <Label text="{{ body }}"></Label>
        <Label text="{{ date }}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you.
My Bad. 
I've written Image selector with margin-bottom and never check it